# What was the earliest printed map in the modern (since 1800) fantasy genre?

Tags: history-of, map

Like many readers, I was enraptured by the maps in J. R. R. Tolkien's *The Lord of the Rings* (1954-55) and *The Hobbit* (1937). After their 1965 reprinting in a widespread American edition, maps became more common in works of science fiction and fantasy. I particularly enjoyed the maps of an imaginary kingdom in Lloyd Alexander's [Prydain Chronicles](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?540)(1964-68) and star charts in Cherryh's [Chanur series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?687)(1982-92).

I think it would be worthwhile to split this question into science fiction and fantasy genres, as these genres have often taken separate paths in literature. I am not sure whether to classify Jonathan Swift's [Gulliver's Travels](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?180697) (1726) as science fiction or as fantasy. This is certainly an early example of speculative fiction illustrated with maps, but I would be more satisfied to find the earliest use of a map in the forebears to the modern genre of fantasy, as it might have influenced later authors.

To sum up: What was the earliest printed map in the fantasy genre? (That is, not merely the earliest map to be mentioned in a text.)

Comment: You'd have to determine where the fantasy genre starts in order to answer. If the definition is that Tolkien invented the genre - well then you have the answer there. If the definition is something with fantastic creatures in some historical setting... well, the Iliad? Some version of Odyssey in print, together with a map?

Comment: @Amarth: Good point. Tolkien had a huge influence on contemporary fantasy writing. But let's start with the early 19th century, taking the cue from the _History of Fantasy_ article in Wikipedia, which points out the difference between older stories that contained fantastical elements and more modern stories that were explicitly intended to belong to fantasy worlds. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_fantasy

Comment: The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe predates LotR by 4 years

Comment: Honorable mention for [*The Dictionary of Imaginary Places*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dictionary_of_Imaginary_Places) which collected (travelogue-style) such map up through the early 1980s (and later in editions after the 1st).

Comment: NKCampbell: Yes, the Narnia map (1949) is older than _The Lord of the Rings_ (http://personal.bgsu.edu/~edwards/baynes.html), but not older than _The Hobbit_ (1937).

Comment: Do you require the map to be of a *fictional world*? I posit that a map of some part of the real world as used for the setting of a fantasy novel wouldn't be within the spirit of the question, but you haven't said so.

Answer (score 10):

**1885**: H. Rider Haggard's *King Solomon's Mines* had a map. This book isn't always categorized as fantasy, but it has an imaginary land and a witch with some powers, plus plenty of mythic destiny, so I think it counts. So does Wikipedia; it is counted among [1885 fantasy novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1885_fantasy_novels).

[image: Map from *King Solomon's Mines*]

**1914**: If *King Solomon's Mines* isn't considered suffiently fantasy, what about L. Frank Baum's *Oz* books? The eight book in the series, *Tik-Tok of Oz*, came with an official map.

[image]

**1932** (addendum): The first "true" fantasy map for adult fantasy may be Robert E. Howard's map of the Hyborian Age, hand-drawn by the writer himself in 1932. The style is very close to the maps we see in fantasy novels today.

[image]

Comment: Both good! Interestingly, Haggard's book ties into the exploration of Africa that was going on at the same time.

Comment: It probably doesn't qualify as fantasy, but Robert Louis Stevenson's *Treasure Island" (1883) had a map of the imaginary Skeleton Island. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Treasure-island-map.jpg

Comment: That Oz map seems to have East/West the wrong way round.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Not as far as I can see. East is to the right, and North on the top, as on most maps.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Munchkin Country (blue) should be East and Winkie (yellow) West.

Comment: Ah, I see. It seems to be a mistake that has propagated to a lot of later maps, including this one. https://i.pinimg.com/originals/20/8e/73/208e7360cad2980c9c8fcae4d2fcf31d.jpg

Comment: Great answer.  I'd kind of class She as "lost kingdom" fiction more than middle of the genre fantasy.  Similar to Crusoe Warburton or even Tarzan.

Answer (score 1):

**Treasure Island, Robert Louis Stevenson, serialized 1881–82, published in book form 14 Nov 1883.**

Wikipedia calls its genre "adventure fiction".

Contains map of titular island:

[image]

Comment: nothing sci/fi fantasy about that story though, so doesn't really answer the question here

Comment: Also, I already linked to that map in a comment to my above post.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, my copy of Jeremiah Post's *An Atlas of Fantasy* (1973, 1979) is in storage and unavailable.

But there is a list of the contents here:

[*An Atlas of Fantasy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Atlas_of_Fantasy[1])

Note that many of the maps included may have been drawn and published years, decades, or centuries after the stories were first published (and may have been published in fanzines, etc. instead of editions of the stories), and that not every work included may qualify as science fiction or fantasy.  Also note that the two editions vary a bit in the maps included.

Therefore it should take some research to decide which is the earliest published fantasy map among the maps published in *An Atlas of Fantasy* (1973, 1979), and of course it is possible that the first fantasy map published is not reproduced in the book.

Comment: "Centuries after" indeed; I hardly think the map of Eden is contemporaneous with the story. :)

Comment: ...this would be better as a comment since none of the research that the answer says would be necessary to actually answer the question is provided. Good info that the book exists though but other than that (and even as you say, it's hard to know if anything in the book is original to the time of the works in question anyway) it's not much use as an answer

Comment: @NK Campbell  It would probably be too long to fit as a comment.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I don't have a copy of _An Atlas of Fantasy_ at hand, but, as you pointed out, Wikipedia has its table of contents and most of the works mentioned therein are linked. As it turns out, the table of contents is given approximately in chronological order. The oldest map is Thomas More's _Utopia_ (1516), which is hard to classify but could be considered as either fantasy or proto-science fiction... (cont.).

Comment: ... And the earliest after the arbitrary cutoff date of 1800 is the fantasy map of Allestone drawn by the young son of Benjamin Heath Malkin and (apparently) printed in _A Father's Memoirs of His Child_ (1806). A map drawn for the 1821 edition of John Bunyan's classic _The Pilgrim's Progress_ is also worthy of note. If you would like to draft an answer pointing out the Malkin map, I can check it as correct so we may reach closure. I think I had a good idea with this question, but the difficulties in answering it meaningfully have become obvious.